# webcam and wifi adapter "break" usb?

Tags: usb, webcam, wifi-driver

I have a webcam, a mouse, and a wifi adapter all plugged into the same USB bus at the back of my computer. When I run a program to utilize the webcam, both the webcam and wifi adapter stop working and do not show up on my computer until I restart it. The moment I run a program to use the webcam, the following is logged to `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.025527] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: force halt; handshake ffffc9000064a824 00004000 00000000 -> -110
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.025530] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: HC died; cleaning up
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.025540] cannot submit urb 1, error -19: no device
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.025570] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.025900] wlan0: deauthenticating from e0:91:f5:ab:2a:f3 by local choice (reason=3)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.136722] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.136731] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel (2462 Mhz) reset status -22
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.136761] ath: phy0: Unable to set channel
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.238761] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.238771] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2462 MHz)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.251867] ath: phy0: Failed to wakeup in 500us
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.261871] ath: phy0: Failed to wakeup in 500us
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.261876] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.261878] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings                                                     
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.261880] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain                                    
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.275777] ath: phy0: Failed to wakeup in 500us                                                        
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.285766] ath: phy0: Failed to wakeup in 500us                                                          
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302587] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:                                                                                                                                               
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302598] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                         
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302604] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:                                                                                                                                                
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302609] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                          
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302613] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:                                                                                                                                                  
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302618] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                            
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302622] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:                                                                                                                                                   
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302627] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                             
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302630] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory ru le:                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302635] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                               
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302639] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory ru  le:                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302643] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                               
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302647] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory ru  le:                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302652] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                               
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302655] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory ru  le:                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302660] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                              
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302664] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory ru le:                                                                                                                                                    
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302668] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)                              
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302672] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302677] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302680] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302685] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302690] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302694] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302698] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302703] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302706] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302713] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302716] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302721] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302726] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302730] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302735] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.302739] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.329820] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
Mar 26 23:10:13 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  121.329966] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
Mar 26 23:10:14 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  122.020091] timeout: still 1 active urbs on EP #83
Mar 26 23:10:15 doug-kubuntu kernel: [  123.017801] timeout: still 1 active urbs on EP #83
```

*Note that the first two lines of the log are similar to the log output when I was using [a USB hub with identical symptoms](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187422/connecting-ipod-or-mp3-player-breaks-usb-contd)

I suspected that the webcam was faulty, [like I suspect a USB hub of mine was](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187422/connecting-ipod-or-mp3-player-breaks-usb-contd). However, if I plug the webcam in one of the USB ports mounted to the front of my computer case, I can use it fine; my wifi adapter still works, and I can use the webcam in skype.

But if I then plug the wifi adapter in the second USB port next to the webcam on the front, they both "break" when I use the webcam. Ideally, I want to use only the back USB ports for both my wifi adapter and my webcam. What is the cause of this? Is my webcam faulty?

hardware info:

- webcam model: Microsoft LifeCam VX-5000 Analog Mono
- wifi adapter model: TP-Link TL-WN722N

Update: While I was trying to figure out how to "map out the USB ports to the motherboard's USB controllers & root hubs", I came across the following question on askubuntu, [My USB ports randomly stop working till a reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69594/my-usb-ports-randomly-stop-working-till-a-reboot), and separately tried both `acpi=force irqpoll` and `noacpi` in my boot options (added to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` and then ran `sudo update-grub`)

Comment: You probably need to map out the USB ports to the motherboard's USB controllers & root hubs.  Seems like the webcam does not play nicely when it has to share a USB host controller with other client devices.

Comment: @sawdust would you care to post an answer with more information on how to do that? I was unable to understand what you suggested from your brief comment.

Comment: Plug in a USB device, and execute the `lsusb` command.  Record the location of that device.  Repeat for each USB port of your PC.  Some ports will be connected to the same bus and USB controller through the built-in **root hubs**.